# How to load more content from server on Scroll in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, scroll, lazy-loading

I want to call API and load more item from database using scroll, initially, I want to display five record only,  then if user scroll and reach bottom of scroll then I want to display five more record. it is about to lazy loading.
 Please I am new to reactjs how can I achieve it.

this is the my code.

```
{this.state.selected ==='text' && <div   style={{overflow:'auto', height:'200px'}}  data-tab-content="tab2">
                                                    {this.state.textList.length>0 ? this.state.textList.map(text=>
                                                   <p  >{text.text} </p>
                                                   ):<p>no record found</p>} */}

                                                   </div>}
```

Here I am making

```
// get Text List
getTextList(){
    debugger
    fetch(baseUrl +`/language/listtext/${'1'}/${'5'}/${this.state.lesson_id}/${this.state.premiumprice_id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())

        .then(data => {
            debugger
          if(data.status ===200){
            debugger
            this.setState({
                textList: data.text.docs,
            })
          }else{
            this.setState({textList : []})
          }


        })
}
```

Thank in advance

Comment: try checking scroll position and then fetch your next data!  you can use this react-scroll library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add onScroll event on div like

```
// for example <div onScroll={this.handleScroll}/>
handleScroll = (e) => {
        const bottom = Number((e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop).toFixed(0)) - e.target.clientHeight < 50;
        let page = this.state.page;
        if (bottom) {
            // write fetching logic here...
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, here I want to know why have put 50, please can  you tell me .

Comment: Because every time the answer of this equation is not equal to zero so the condition will not true so i put less than 50 it means the scroll is almost move to bottom here is the equation : (e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop).toFixed(0)) - e.target.clientHeight

Comment: ok, Great explanation, a little issue, if my scroll height is 200px  and initially I am displaying 5 record which  height is less the 200 px so in that case scroll  will not  be visible and I won't able to fetch rest data.

Comment: i think you should decrease the height so that scroll will enable otherwise if scroll will not enable onScroll event will not triggered.

Comment: or load 10 record initially so that scroll enabled.